# MySQL broad schema vs multiple tables

Tags: mysql, schema, database-schema, data-modeling

I'm currently modeling the schema for a project which will be using MySQL 5.5. I'm having issues, however with a current feature that's being requested. This feature would require there to be very specific sum of data pertaining to a certain "specialty". There are 47 specialties, and this will rarely change(possibly never). The problem is each of these 47 specialties would require its own table with a different schema.

This would mean my "programs" table will contain 47 different foreign keys, only one of which would bare an actual relation. This seems inefficient to me. However, adding possibly a thousand values to a single table doesn't seem much better, as most of those values won't be provided in any given scenario.

I feel like I'm choosing the better of 2 evils. Though the thought crossed my mind to embed these fields in a TEXT column without a schema, possibly as JSON. These fields don't need to be indexed, but this approach feels dirty also.

I've never dealt with an issue such as this. Is there any alternative to the approaches I mentioned? If not, what approach is best and why?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482012/is-there-such-a-thing-as-too-many-tables) SO article which would seem to support having 47 different tables if this really solves your problem.

Comment: What if you decided to do without FOREIGN KEYs?

Comment: I like the JSON approach better than key-value store:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav .

Comment: @RickJames What if I did? How would I do so?

I need to bare some relation between the tables by having some sort of index. A foreign key would is just a key that is pointing to the primary key of the row in that specific table. How else would I create a relation?

JSON seems dirty because I'm duplicating data all over, its schema-less, and if the structure were to change it would be very painful to migrate that data.

Comment: @RickJames Or are you implying that I embed json in a column, in the place of multiple foreign keys?

Comment: A FOREIGN KEY is (1) an index and (2) a constraint and (3) optionally a 'cascading' action.  (1) can be done with INDEX.  (2) is a check that the data is consistent; it is not required.  (3) is something that is easily simulated in code.  I never use FKs; I prefer to maintain control over my schema with INDEXes and code.

Comment: A column in a table might (1) be used for uniquely identifying a row (PRIMARY KEY), or (2) provide a uniqueness constraint plus an index (UNIQUE KEY), or (3) some data to manipulate (SUM(revenue)), or (4) just a blob of stuff to store and retrieve (a .jpg in a BLOB, text to throw on a web page (TEXT)).  In some situations, I see JSON as just a blob of stuff to store (INSERT) and retrieve (SELECT) but never UPDATE in index.  Because it has structure inside it, JSON provides structured data for the application, but not for MySQL.

Comment: Am I saying you should abandon FKs?  And use JSON?  Not necessarily.  I am suggesting you should consider them.  I don't really understand your application enough.  Note that I did not give you an "Answer", but rather a "Comment".  If you could give us a tentative CREATE TABLE for a couple of the 47, that might help guide me toward either pushing for JSON or abandoning it.  Also, a couple of SELECTs would help.

Comment: @RickJames We have a specialties table with a row for each specialty. There are 47 different specialties. Each specialty will have certain unique data that correlates to that specialty, and depending on the program for that specialty there will be different values but the same attributes. So duplicate data might not be a huge issue, especially because these programs don't typically change. I guess what I meant by a foreign key is an index rather.